# Is there a reason StringBuilder insert uses String.valueOf?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, stringbuilder

In the JDK source for [AbstractStringBuilder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java) the [`append(int)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.append%28int%29) method is implemented in a way that does not allocate unnecessary memory (writing directly to the internal `char[]` using `Integer.getChars`).

But the implementation for [`insert`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.insert%28int%2Cint%29) uses `String.valueOf` which returns a new string and then copies that data into the array. Creating a garbage string.

Isn't one of the points of a `StringBuilder` to mitigate the garbage impact of concatenating strings. And a garbage-free implementation of `insert` seems trivial to implement. So why isn't it?

This seems to be the case in both the Oracle JDK and OpenJDK. It is even mentioned in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert-int-int-):

> The overall effect is exactly as if the second argument were converted to a string by the method String.valueOf(int), and the characters of that string were then inserted into this character sequence at the indicated offset.

Comment: The implementation of `insert` doesn’t affect the goal of “mitigating the garbage impact of concatenating strings” as concatenation never needs an *insert* operation. Being less common, reducing the code duplication has been considered more important than reducing the garbage. Apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compare `insert(int,int)` with the other `insert` methods, you will recognize that the implementation approach was to keep it simple, reducing the code duplication by letting a single `insert(String)` method do all the actual work.

This is a reasonable approach in software development, first create a straight-forward general implementation handling all cases, then do profiling with real applications & scenarios to find the places where creating a specialized, perhaps not so simple, optimized version has a benefit. It seems that no search was made to find other places where the same optimized implementation could be used. Considering that the preceding measurement apparently didn’t reveal `insert(int,int)` as an important hot spot, that doesn’t hurt.

To evaluate the situation, it is important to understand that not the number of temporary objects makes repeated `String.concat` expensive. Excessive creation of temporary objects may add fuel to the flames so it’s still worth avoiding it if there is a simple option. But the problem with repeated `String.concat` calls is that the creation of each temporary string instance implies copying of the entire character data that makes up the string contents. The more `concat` calls your string building does, the closer you will get to a quadratic time complexity.

The `StringBuilder` solves this by using a mutable buffer. It’s still copied when the capacity is exhausted, but by using a factor to determine the new capacity, the overall time complexity stays linear. The implementation of `insert` doesn’t change this fundamental principle. The temporary `String` instance only causes a copying of the right-hand side, so it only introduces a constant factor of two rather than changing the time complexity.

But don’t forget that `insert` bears a copying of the buffer’s subsequent character data in principle. If you repeatedly insert at the beginning of the buffer, you’ll steer towards a quadratic time complexity, regardless of how much optimized the underlying implementation is. So the factor of two will become negligible anyway if you’re doing this excessively.

Comment: I'm working in an environment where any gc allocations are unacceptable, even if there is more CPU work to do. So the insert method is not usable. Guess I'll have to do some hacks to get something similar working gc free.

Comment: Well, you know, there are allocations anyway if the capacity is exhausted. On the other hand, if you can predict the right initial capacity, you should also be able to rewrite the operation to use `append` (and perhaps a second buffer for the subsequent content). Then, you’re not only avoiding allocations, but also reducing the copying costs. If copying costs do not matter to you, you can avoid the allocation as easy as using `secondary.append(42); primary.insert(offset, secondary); secondary.setLength(0); secondary.append(101); primary.insert(offset, secondary); secondary.setLength(0);`, etc.

Comment: This is basically what I did, though using one of appends overloads to only insert part of the initial string, append the insertion and then append the rest of the string. Used it to make a convenient GC free way of formatting text.

Comment: You mean like `builder.append(original, 0, pos).append(itemToInsert).append(original, pos, original.length()).toString()`? That’s better than using `insert`, even CPU-wise.

Comment: Yes that is basically what I did. Works like a charm so far.